# Executing process on rooted phone with invalid params

Tags: android, unix, process, terminal, busybox

Suppose this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(SU);
DataOutputStream processStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
processStream.writeChars("cat /qwerty");
processStream.writeChars(EXIT);
processStream.flush();

int status = process.waitFor();

Log.d("EXIT STATUS", String.valueOf(status));
```

`process.waitFor();` causes current thread to wait forever. I guess the problem is with that invalid command(I made that deliberately). But how do I handle such situations?

**Busybox 1.17.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send commands using the writeChars, they are all going on the same line in the shell and never being actually executed I think.  You need to put newlines in to make the shell execute.  Try this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(SU);
DataOutputStream processStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
processStream.writeChars("cat /qwerty\n");
processStream.writeChars("exit \n");
processStream.flush();

int status = process.waitFor();

Log.d("EXIT STATUS", String.valueOf(status));
```